# Reduction to complement of Accept Problem

Tags: computability, turing-machines, reductions, undecidability

I am reducing a given Turing Machine to the complement of the known undecidable problem, 
$$ Complement(A_{TM}) = \{ \langle M,w \rangle \mid M  \text{ is TM}, w \not\in L(M) \}$$

To this Turing Machine, known as SPARSE TM:
$$
SPARSE_{TM} = \{ \langle M \rangle \mid M \text{ is 1-tape TM}, |L(M)| \leq 1000\} 
$$

Here is what I have so far, but I think I need help because one of the statements I make seems fishy.

Assume there is a TM `S` that decides the complement of the accept TM and a TM `R` that decides SPARSE. Then `S` looks like:

```
S = "On input `<M,w>`:
    Construct M':
        M' = "On input x:
            if x in L(M):  #Fishy statement
                accept
            else: reject
     Run R on <M'>
     if R accepts: accept; if R rejects: reject
```

This (if right) would then reduce the SPARSE TM and prove that it is undeciable, right? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: 1) These objects you define are not Turing machines, they are languages. In fact, you claim they are *not* equivalent to any Turing machine. 2) Which of your statements are you having trouble with?

Comment: Sorry if I'm not being clear. I am reducing the SPARSE-TM to the complement of the A-TM. However, I don't think I am doing it correctly. I'm trying to prove that SPARSE-TM being decidable implies that complement of A-TM is decidable, which is impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When reducing $L_1$ to $L_2$, we need to come up with a computable mapping $f$ such that $x \in L_1$ iff $f(x) \in L_2$. We don't start with a Turing machine deciding $L_2$ and then construct one for deciding $L_1$, although this construction can easily be accomplished using the mapping $f$. The reason we refrain from doing so is that sometimes we already know that $L_2$ is undecidable, and yet there is merit in saying that $L_1$ reduces to $L_2$, since $L_1$ might have an even strong guarantee of "hardness"; this sort of thinking leads to classical recursion theory.

Regarding your construction, there are two problems: (1) it doesn't involve $w$, (2) when you write "if $x \in L(M)$", you actually mean "simulate $M$ on $x$"; this simulation could halt, or it could never halt. Generally speaking, when a Turing machine never halts, then we say that it rejects. See if this fits with what you were trying to accomplish.

Comment: Okay thank you for catching that I'm not using w. I think I can go ahead with this with your suggestions. Thanks